# Xamarin - Using httpClient in .Net Standard Library

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I've created Xamarin project, and I added several .Net standard class libraries to it (one for each layer: data access, service layer etc.). Then, In ServiceLayer project, I implemented method, which fetch data from my Web API (external ASP Net Core project). When it comes to httpClient.GetAsync(), android app crash. What's more, when I cut this piece of code, and paste it in default xamarin .Net standard library, everything works. Any ideas?

Code is here:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

UPDATE:

In Viewmodel:

```
constructor(IServiceLayerService service){
        _ServiceLayerService = service;
        GetTestCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await GetTests());
        }     

        public async Task GetTests()
        {
            TestObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<List<Test>>(await _ServiceLayerService.GetTestModels());
        }
```

Update 2: 
I've changed my async method call, in the way presented in first answer. Now, when I'm trying to execute code, app also crashes, but I'm receiving error messages:

```
07-05 14:39:04.518 F/        (25383): /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-7/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4897: Could not execute the method because the containing type is not fully instantiated. assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null) signature:<none>
07-05 14:39:04.518 F/libc    (25383): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 25383 (com.companyname), pid 25383 (com.companyname)
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with Unity dependency injection, so here is registration of service layer classes in App.xaml.cs

```
 protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<TestsListPage, TestsListViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.Register<IServiceLayerService, ServiceLayerService>();
}
```

Comment: How and where is the code being called when it crashes? Are you making any blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()`?

Comment: I'm injecting class from ServiceLayer project to ViewModel, and then, in command I'm executing it.

Comment: Show that. chances are you have an async void in the command that is not allowing you to catch the exception.

Comment: I've updated question with code

Comment: Yep  `GetTestCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await GetTests());` create an async void. Create an event handler and raise that in the command.

Comment: If it's problem, why this code works: `public async Task GetTests()
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient; var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);                          
        }`?

Comment: That code will work. The problem is how and where it is being called. The async command delegate is the culprit

Comment: Check to make sure that all relevant dependencies are registered so that all object graphs can be constructed when resolved.

Comment: Every dependency works instead of one. I don't know why. If I move httpClient to different dependency, it works, if I move it back, it don't. I think I'll give up, and move it to different place. I tried even changing order of dependencies registration, or resolving dependency manually in constructor, but nothing works. One difference between ServiceLayer class and other dependencies, is that I'm using generic methods in it, but I think it is impossible that it is a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the async command delegate

```
GetTestCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await GetTests());
```

The command delegate results in an `async void`, which wont allow exceptions to be caught as they are considered fire and forget methods

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Create an event and handler to manage the async call

```
private event EventHandler gettingTests = delegate { };
private async void OnGettingTests(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    try {
        await GetTests();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //...handle exception
    }
}
```

*Note that event handlers are the one exception to the rule that allows `async void`*

Subscribe to the event in the constructor and raise the event in the command delegate

```
constructor (IServiceLayerService service) {
    _ServiceLayerService = service;
    this.gettingTests += OnGettingTests;
    GetTestCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => gettingTests(this, EventArgs.Empty));
}
```

So now when the command is invoked, it will raise the event and the async handler can make async calls correctly.

Comment: I've changed my method call in the way You presented, but app is still crashing. I placed breakpoint, and noticed that app is crashing inside ServiceLayer project after GetStringAsync call. Unfortunetely without any exception. Last message from output is: `xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4897: Could not execute the method because the containing type is not fully instantiated. assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null) signature:<none>
 (25383): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 25383 (name), pid 25383 (name)`

Comment: @Movart but now you can catch the exception to see what is the cause and trouble shoot. With async void delegate you were not able to do that.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and thank you. Now I see those messages and I'm trying to fix them. I think, I'm doing something wrong with Unity dependency injection, but I can't figure out what